# How to convert binary data into an image in React.js?

Tags: mern

I'm trying to show the image in react which i have uploaded in the mongoDB using node & express.
I'm getting the image in node but in react i'm unable to show the image since the data is in binary.
Response data:

```
{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":

[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,205,0,0,0,205,8,3,0,0,

0,44,98,4,91,0,0,1,59,80,76,84,69,255,255,255,32,31,31,244,202,177,156,218,

240,124,186,230,0,0,0,....
```

I have tried the following code for conversion but it didn't work.

```
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}
```

Also tried this

How can I convert the data to show that in the react application?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but someone can find it useful.

Try to convert your image to base64 string like

```
objImg.img = new Buffer.from(bitMap).toString("base64")
```

And then when you get the image from request set your state like

```
setPreviewImg("data:image/png;base64," + result.img)
```